# Using mask in iPhone programing with OpenGL

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I'm wondering there is any easy way to use masks/cliping with openGL in objective C? At the moment I'm researching cocos2d but there peapole say that this is complex problem. What is Your opinion?

Update:
Ofcoure my bad. My gole is to draw puzzle with ccDrawCubicBezier, and then clip to that some sprite.

Comment: Can you provide any more information about what sort of masking or clipping you're thinking of, and what code you already have? Are you trying to augment an existing UIKit application with some clipping or writing a new application from scratch? If the latter then what other sort of tasks do you want to be able to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using cocos2d the approach you take will vary depending on whether you use cocos2d v1.x (openGL ES 1.0)  or cocos2d v2.x (openGL ES 2.0).

For v1.0 you can use openGL Blending and cocos2d's CCRenderTexture, covered here;

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4421/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-1-0

For v2.0 you can use a custom shader

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4428/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-2-0